# Stats: Accuracy of the KNN algorithm for K=1

Tags: algorithm, machine-learning, statistics, knn

This is really a general question about the KNN algorithm that hopefully you will be able to help me understand.

I use the knn algorithm in the library class in R:

knn <- knn(train=X_train, test=X_test, cl=train_Y, k=3)

When running the KNN algorithm for a classification of handwritten digits from 0 to 9 (each observation is a txt file with 1024 0s and 1s creating the picture of a number). So it's a dataset with 1024 variables and each of them can be 0 or 1.

I am able to run the algorithm and I get very good results with K=3 (somehow reasonable). However, when I loop through different K values looking for an optimal value it happens that the optimal K values are either 1 or 3, then it descends gradually.

What I find odd is the fact that K=1 can be an optimal value as I don't find it reasonable that looking only at the closest point should be the optimal value.

Can you help me with this matter? Could it be because of the Argument use.all = TRUE?

Comment: "Could it be because of the Argument use.all = TRUE?", you tried with `FALSE` and you inspired to ask that question?

Comment: It's interesting. With use.all=FALSE I get a slightly worse result, but again k=1 and k=3 are the most accurate. I get the best results when use.all=TRUE. And if I don't put anything, I get a slightly different result, in between TRUE and FALSE. I tried it many times (as results may vary when using use.all=FALSE)